# `Unable to open file` when creating Dataflow job from CLI

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm trying to upload/run an Apache Beam project on GCS Dataflow, but I get

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Defaulting to the temp_location as staging_location: gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/dataflow_python_sdk.tar...
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Completed GCS upload to gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/dataflow_python_sdk.tar in 0 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/apache_beam-2.37.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl...
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Completed GCS upload to gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/apache_beam-2.37.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl in 2 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Starting GCS upload to gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/pipeline.pb...
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Completed GCS upload to gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/pipeline.pb in 0 seconds.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Create job: <Job
 clientRequestId: '20220329131716993627-8183'
 createTime: '2022-03-29T13:17:21.318402Z'
 currentStateTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z'
 id: '2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924'
 location: 'europe-west4'
 name: 'beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr'
 projectId: '---'
 stageStates: []
 startTime: '2022-03-29T13:17:21.318402Z'
 steps: []
 tempFiles: []
 type: TypeValueValuesEnum(JOB_TYPE_STREAMING, 2)>
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Created job with id: [2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924]
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:Submitted job: 2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient:To access the Dataflow monitoring console, please navigate to https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/jobs/europe-west4/2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924?project=---
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:Job 2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924 is in state JOB_STATE_PENDING
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2022-03-29T13:17:21.841Z: JOB_MESSAGE_WARNING: Autoscaling is enabled for Dataflow Streaming Engine. Workers will scale between 1 and 100 unless maxNumWorkers is specified.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2022-03-29T13:17:21.965Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling is enabled for job 2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924. The number of workers will be between 1 and 100.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2022-03-29T13:17:21.977Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling was automatically enabled for job 2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2022-03-29T13:17:22.655Z: **JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Unable to open file: gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/pipeline.pb.**
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:Job 2022-03-29_06_17_20-16155411029565657924 is in state JOB_STATE_FAILED
```

**JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Unable to open file: gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/pipeline.pb.**

My account has all the required roles (such as `Dataflow admin` etc). The funny/weird thing is that the bucket is accessed fine (when uploading) so I suspect the error to be something else than access permissions.

The pipeline runs fine with the `DirectRunner`

Running the WordCount / Hello World example renders the same error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apache-beam-env/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apache-beam-env/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apache-beam-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line 105, in <module>
    run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apache-beam-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line 100, in run
    output | 'Write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apache-beam-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 597, in __exit__
    self.result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/apache-beam-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1636, in wait_until_finish
    raise DataflowRuntimeException(
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
Unable to open file: gs://***-pipelines/tmp/beamapp-sc-0330081654-908129-1819ty70.1648628214.908300/pipeline.pb.
```
````

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Can you verify that the file gs://dataflow-staging-europe-west4-10a485e03dda20c80122afcef299fc02/beamapp-sc-0329131716-990957-kruh5vvr.1648559836.992112/pipeline.pb.** does indeed exist?

Comment: The file exists yes. 
The (apache beam) SDK is latest Conda build of it (miniforge3/conda-bld/apache-beam-split_1646465333696/work)

Comment: apache-beam=2.37

Comment: running the Wordcount example renders the same error
I've added the Traceback in the orig question

Answer (score 1):

Fixed ... Apparently Google is using the `Compute Engine` default service account to *run* the pipeline instead of the one set with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (if it exists I presume)